# peerjs connection opens, but no data is received

Tags: node.js, websocket, webrtc, node-webkit, peerjs

Here's my setup

Server

```
var webrtcServer = new PeerServer({
    port: 9000,
    path: "/wrtc"
});
```

Peer 1 (running inside a node-webkit application)

```
var peer = new Peer( 'masterName', {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 9000,
    path: '/wrtc'
});

peer.on( 'connection', function(conn) {
    conn.on( 'open', function() {
        console.log( "peer connected" );          // This fires as expected
        conn.send( "helo" );
    });
});
```

Peer 2 (running inside a browser)

```
conn = peer.connect('masterName');
conn.on('open', function(){
    console.log( "WebRTC connection open" );      // This fires as expected
});

conn.on('data', function(data) { 
    debugger; 
    console.log("data");                          // This never hits
});
```

If I set breakpoints in peer.js, no data is being received. Nothing changes if I set the connection to reliable. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: I currently have a similar problem and I suspect that it is linked to some networking issue. See "Why am I unable to connect" in the [docs](http://peerjs.com/docs/). Have you tried running the two peers on the same machine? That works for me, also when I use your code.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem and adding a STUN server solved it for me. Also have a look this discussion in the [peerjs Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/peerjs/JzIr7INoTbQ/IIykVNHiv_sJ)

```
peer = new Peer(
        {
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 9000,
          debug: true,
          config: { 'iceServers': [
            { 'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }  
          ] }
        });
```